# Angular error "n.is is not a function" when including ng-model into input field of sign up -why?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, angular-ngmodel, materialize

I am using nodejs for the backend and angular for the fronend (and using materialize for css) and trying to write code for the signup. When I remove ng-model I get no errors, however, when I include ng-model in the input, the moment I start typing in the password/email field, I get a weird angular error : TypeError: n.is is not a function or TypeError: n.trigger is not a function . I have no idea what -n- is and dont have n function anywhere. Have been searching the internet etc. but cant figure out whats wrong.Also, signup does not work (it did before). Anyone has an idea? Thank you!

browser/js/signup.html

```
<div class="signup-wrapper">
   <form id="signup-form" name="signupForm" ng-submit="signupForm.$valid && sendSignup(signup)">
        <alert type="danger" ng-show="error"> {{ error }} </alert> 
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email" >Email address</label>
         <input style="width:300px;" type="text" ng-model="signup.email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="signup-password">Password</label>
         <input style="width:300px;" type="password" ng-model="signup.password" class="form-control" id="signup-password" placeholder="Password">
         <input type="password" ng-model="signup.confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      </div>
      <div class="signup-btn-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

browser/js/signup.js:

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {

```
$stateProvider.state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'js/signup/signup.html',
    controller: 'SignupController'
});
```

});

```
  app.controller('SignupController', function ($scope, AuthFactory, $state) {
    $scope.signup = {}; 

    $scope.sendSignup = function (signupInfo) {
        AuthFactory.signup(signupInfo)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response === 'email exists already') {
                Materialize.toast('User already exists', 2000);
            } 
            else if (response === 'not a valid email'){
                Materialize.toast('It is not a valid email', 2000);
            }
            else if (response === 'passwords do not match'){
                Materialize.toast('Your passwords do not match. Please try again!', 2000);
            }
            else {
                 Materialize.toast('Go ahead and login', 4000);
                $state.go('login');
            }
        })
    }

});
```

server/app/configure/authentication/local.js:

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {

 var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
 var test = re.test(req.body.email);
 if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirm) {
    res.send('passwords do not match')
 } else if (!test) {
    res.send('not a valid email')
 } else {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    }).then(function(userOrNull) {
        if (userOrNull) {
            res.send('email exists already')
        } else {
            User.create(req.body)
                .then(function(user) {
                    req.login(user, function(err) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        res.redirect('/login');
                    })
                })
        }

    })
  }
});
```

EDIT:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/materialize-css/bin/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
<script src="/lodash/index.js"></script>
<script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/materialize-css/bin/materialize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular-materialize/src/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the complete error message, it probably includes a stack trace with filenames and line numbers. Also if its in angular it probably includes a link to a very helpful page on the angular website that will tell you a lot more about the error.

Comment: angular.js:14110 TypeError: n.trigger is not a function
    at angular-materialize.min.js:1
    at angular.js:19861
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:6035)
    at angular.js:6314

Comment: Thank you. I couldnt see a link

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to load your jQuery even before you load Angular.

This ensures that Angular can use the full jQuery library instead of jQlite.

Answer (score 1):

Well had same issue with slick.min.js and angular-slick.min.js and after killing lots of time searching for solution finally I figured it out that issue was simple and my commonsense was not working.

I added the js files in following order and the error was gone. Hope someone finds it useful:

```
1) jquery.min.js
2) jquery-ui.min.js
3) slick.min.js
4) angular.js
5) angular-filter.js
6) angular-slick.min.js
...
...
```

In your case can try the following order and see if it works

```
<script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/materialize-css/bin/materialize.js"></script>
<script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-materialize/src/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="/lodash/index.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check to see if the form is $valid should be happening in your .js file. So on success, $scope.signupForm.$valid = true; and you would just have the sendSignup method call.

Also your sign up form is looking for some $scope.signup.confirm = true.. Which is why it could not be working (I dont see you actually using that).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: thank you. I removed the form validation just to see if the error message would keep coming up and it does so that cant be the problem.Also, I dont really understand what y you mean with signup.confirm - I need that to compare there passwords and if I remove it, i just keep getting the error message that passwords dont match.

Answer (score 0):

You added more of the error message in a comment:

```
angular.js:14110 TypeError: n.trigger is not a function
 at angular-materialize.min.js:1
 at angular.js:19861
 at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:6035)
 at angular.js:6314
```

So, although you didn't mention it in the question, you are using the `angular-materialize` module and it is that module which is throwing the error. Looking at the uncompressed sources for angular-materialize I can see that it is expecting to find a `trigger` method on DOM elements.

The readme file for that module says:

> Angular looks for jQuery and if no exists, it uses jQlite. Some
>   directives of angular-materialize uses some jQuery methods, so be sure
>   that Angular uses it instead of jQlite.

I think your problem is simply that you've used a module which depends on jQuery but you haven't included jQuery in your app.

Comment: thanks for for your answer. I edited my question and included my script tags. I npm installed jquery and have the jquery script tag (added it before materialize as thats what the materialize documentation says) is there something wrong with my script tags or the order? Thank you!